# Are variables allowed in a PL/SQL INSERT query?

Tags: sql, plsql, insertion

Is it allowed to use Insert query with variables?

Like:
  Insert Into var_1 (col1_Var_Name, col2_vAr_Name)
  Values (var_3, var_4)

?

Comment: We are looking for questions that are well researched and demonstrate some actual work done by the author of the OP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Table and column names cannot be passed to a statement as variables. One way to accomplish what you seem to be trying to do is to build the statement as a string and then execute it dynamically, as in:

```
DECLARE
  strStmt   VARCHAR2(2000);
  strTable  VARCHAR2(30) := 'SOME_TABLE';
  strCol1   VARCHAR2(30) := 'COL1';
  strCol2   VARCHAR2(30) := 'COL2';
  strCol3   VARCHAR2(30) := 'COL3';
  nVal1     NUMBER       := 42;
  strVal2   VARCHAR2(30) := 'HELLO';
  nVal3     NUMBER       := 100;
BEGIN
  strStmt := 'INSERT INTO ' || strTable ||
               '(' || strCol1 || ',' ||
                      strCol2 || ',' ||
                      strCol3 || ')' ||
               ' VALUES (' ||
                         nVal1   || ','    ||
                         '''' || strVal2 || ''',' ||
                         nVal3 || ')';

  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE strStmt;
END;
```

Share and enjoy.

Comment: thanks, great answer, though google replied faster :) now i have Dynamic sql queries:)

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE
   TYPE type_name IS TABLE OF
      (column_type |
      variable%TYPE |
      table.column%TYPE
         [NOT NULL]
            INDEX BY BINARY INTEGER;
```

fOR MORE INFO [Declare Table type variable](http://ss64.com/oraplsql/declaretbl.html)

Comment: Can you please explain what is %TYPE using a nice example

Comment: Did you see the link below the syntax? @Batousik